# Format string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `dart`

I have a string like this

```
Hello @[Nguyễn Anh Tài](8a66c420-8b21-4ebd-adfc-2ede6128d143) 
@[Hồng Anh](272276cd-e9ca-4463-b5b6-b254b6770be7) 123 
@[Lê Đình Duy](bbc78074-722f-46d5-a29c-dff304d4ef8a) 456 
@[Trần Thị Lưu](15c5f175-0205-42a6-b8a0-6b78cf89c5f3)
```

How can I format that string into:

```
Hello Nguyễn Anh Tài
Hồng Anh 123 
Lê Đình Duy 456 
Trần Thị Lưu
```

Comment: Would you please share, what you have already tried? What is the rule you try to implement?

Answer (score 1):

You could use String.replaceAll method https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html .

```dart
  var src =
      'Hello @Nguyễn Anh Tài and @Hồng Anh 123 @Lê Đình Duy 456 @Trần Thị Lưu';
  var result = src.replaceAll('@', '');
  print(result);
```

Hope this helps.